# Laptop with spare M.2 Key A/E slot inside?

Tags: laptop

I'm looking for a laptop in which I can plug in a [PicoEVB](https://www.crowdsupply.com/rhs-research/picoevb) board without having to sacrifice my wireless connectivity or having to drag more hardware around with me.

So far I'm using this board in a server w/ an adapter (meant for NGFF Wi-Fi & Bluetooth chips) and it works really nicely, but I wish for some portability.

As far as the rest of the laptop's specifications go, at least 8 GB of RAM and generally a beefier CPU is better, but I might settle for some weaker ones if there's an advantage (e.g. battery life).

Even a spare M.2 Key M slot could be handy with [one of these babies](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B079NB8J3B). Provided that there's a USB header available inside as well, of course...

Comment: Sure, there are plenty. What's your budget like? Screen size, resolution, color accuracy? Use case? Power vs. portability vs. battery life?

Comment: @JMY1000 Well, I'm broke but I'm willing to look at higher end laptops to start saving. Screen should be 14" at worst, 15" or larger would be ideal. 1080p at least. I don't know what to say about color accuracy, I'm not a designer + I'm colorblind. My use case is, eh, already stated here. I need that piece of hardware in the laptop, for which I need that spare slot. The laptop can either be a powerhouse (in which case weight and battery life matter less, if it's got a strong CPU) or portable (in which case it should be light-ish and with a decent battery life) - either extreme is fine.

Comment: Regarding the power/portability/battery matter, I just don't like failed attempts at having the best of all 3. I know there are some spectacular balances achieved in some laptops, but those typically make my bank account weep.

Comment: What about just getting a USB wi-fi adapter?

Comment: @JMY1000 I guess that is a valid option, although it's going to be slightly inconvenient for a laptop that's meant to be portable.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm just having a lot of trouble finding any laptop that would have another wi-fi card (the only reason for a properly keyed M.2 slot I can think of), and no luck with an M.2 slot tall enough that would fit the adapter (let alone a free USB header.)

Comment: @JMY1000 I wonder what reasons a manufacturer could have to install two different wireless cards onto a laptop motherboard. Regarding the M key adapter, by tall enough you mean having room in the case for the extra card on top of it? Or with enough space to fit its length?

Comment: I can't think of one besides a few specialty applications (like accessing an internet connected network and one without it, like for robotics), which is probably why it doesn't exist, since their approach is probably just "Go get another wi-fi adapter." I meant room in the case.

Comment: @JMY1000 Here's another option: 4G modem + some type of dock. This + a M.2 Key A/E for Wi-Fi inside would be good enough as well. Most laptops designed for portability nowadays have a dock (even 3rd party cheap-o ones). And if the laptop is designed for power (and isn't very portable), I think an Ethernet port is enough for me.